# how to implement high availability service (2 nodes) using zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

i need to provide a H/A mechanism.

i understand thet zookeeper can be chosen as a leader election

i'm looking for the right pattern for this flow:

i need to implement a service that invoke a flow.
when it starting the flow [the flow is a looping flow], it must validate that it is the leader. (say by it's ip address).

i understand that i can put a value into a zookeeper that define that entering 
instance, and dispose it when 1 loop end, or for a period of time.

it is that the right pattern?

also it seems that race condition issues if i use something like:

```
...
...
List<String> names = zk.getChildren( path, false );
String id = null;
// See whether we have already run for election in this process
for ( String name : names ) {
{
   if ( name.startsWith( myIP ) ) {
      id = name;
      break;
   }
}
if ( id == null ) {
id = zk.create( path + "/" + myIP, new byte[0], ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
}
boolean isLeader = id != null;
```

for example:

2 services read null
and than 2nd overrides the 1st signature, and both of them running the task.

can you help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ZooKeeper correctly can be difficult and takes some studying of its APIs and semantics.  There are some nice high-level libraries such as Curator that already have implemented common algorithms such as [leader election](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-election.html).  The ZooKeeper documentation also has a [recipe for leader election](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection).